# Vivado simulation stuck at 0 fs

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl, simulation, hdl, vivado

I am trying to simulate a D flip flop using Vivado 2018.2.2.
But upon running the simulation a window pops up stating Current time: 0 fs. The program doesn't freeze, it just doesn't progress. Here is the code:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;

ENTITY Dff IS
    port (d, clk, rst: in std_logic;
          q      : out std_logic);
END ENTITY Dff;

ARCHITECTURE behav OF Dff IS
BEGIN
   main : PROCESS
   BEGIN
      IF rst='1' THEN
          q <= '0';
      ELSIF rising_edge(clk) THEN
          q <= d;
      END IF;
  END PROCESS main;
END ARCHITECTURE behav;
```

And the test bench:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY Dff_tb IS
END Dff_tb;

ARCHITECTURE behav OF Dff_tb IS
    CONSTANT T : time := 10 ns;
    CONSTANT N : INTEGER := 3;
    COMPONENT Dff
    PORT(
        d : IN std_logic;
        clk : IN std_logic;
        rst : IN std_logic;
        q : OUT std_logic
    );
    END COMPONENT;

    SIGNAL d : std_logic := '0';
    SIGNAL clk : std_logic := '0';
    SIGNAL rst : std_logic := '0';
    SIGNAL q : std_logic;
    SIGNAL sim_data : std_logic_vector (N downto 0) := "0011";     
BEGIN
    Dff_0 : Dff PORT MAP (d => d, clk => clk, rst=>rst, q => q);

    clk_pr : PROCESS 
    BEGIN
        clk <= '0';
        WAIT FOR T/2;
        clk <= '1';
        WAIT FOR T/2;
    END PROCESS clk_pr;

    main_pr : PROCESS
    VARIABLE i : INTEGER := 0;
    BEGIN
      rst <= '1';
      wait for T*2; 

      rst <= '0';
      d <= '0';
      wait for T*2;

      rst <= '0';
      d <= '1';  
      wait; 
    END PROCESS main_pr;
END ARCHITECTURE behav;
```

I am new to VHDL so It is probably something obvious.
Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
Following a comment, I edited my test bench code like this:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY Dff_tb IS
END Dff_tb;

ARCHITECTURE behav OF Dff_tb IS
    CONSTANT T : time := 10 ns;
    CONSTANT N : INTEGER := 3;
    COMPONENT Dff
    PORT(
        d : IN std_logic;
        clk : IN std_logic;
        rst : IN std_logic;
        q : OUT std_logic
    );
    END COMPONENT;

    SIGNAL d : std_logic := '0';
    SIGNAL clk : std_logic := '0';
    SIGNAL rst : std_logic := '0';
    SIGNAL q : std_logic;
    SIGNAL sim_data : std_logic_vector (N downto 0) := "0011";  
    SHARED VARIABLE sim_end : boolean := false;   
BEGIN
    Dff_0 : Dff PORT MAP (d => d, clk => clk, rst=>rst, q => q);

    clk_pr : PROCESS 
    BEGIN
        IF sim_end = false THEN
            clk <= '0';
            WAIT FOR T/2;
            clk <= '1';
            WAIT FOR T/2;
        ELSE
            WAIT;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS clk_pr;

    main_pr : PROCESS
    VARIABLE i : INTEGER := 0;
    BEGIN
      rst <= '1';
      wait for T*2; 

      rst <= '0';
      d <= '0';
      wait for T*2;

      rst <= '0';
      d <= '1';
      sim_end := true;
      wait; 
    END PROCESS main_pr;
END ARCHITECTURE behav;
```

But the problem stil persists.

Comment: Did you assign clock signal to be a clock?

Comment: No, I did'nt. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Besides the problem mentioned below, I found the problem in the `Dff` entity itself (I was focused on the testbench, sorry for that): The main process hasn't any `wait` statement of any sort. Either add a sensitivity list to `main` process:

```
main : PROCESS (clk, rst)
```

Or add a wait statement inside `main` process:

```
wait on clk, rst;
```

That should fix it.

Your simulation doesn't terminate since the `clk_pr` process will run forever. Here's a simple solution:

```
--- clock generator
clk <= not clk after 50 ns when finished /= '1' else '0';

--- rest of your test bench
main_pr : PROCESS

--- test code

--- stop clock
finished <= '1';
wait;
END PROCESS;
```

Of course you can replace `50 ns` with the constant you use, remember to add a `finished` signal to the test bench initialized to `'0'`.

Comment: I tried it, but the problem did not go away (see the edit for the new code).

Comment: I updated my answer, I can get it to run in Vivado now.

Comment: This isn’t right. You don’t need an enable on the clock. A simulation doesn’t end because the clock stopped; it ends because you stop simulating.

Comment: Yes, but this will stop many simulators without extra information or commands (say, when no signals are driven). It really depends on your toolchain; I mainly use GHDL on the command line, so stopping the simulation by stopping the clock saves me time and simplifies my workflow.

Comment: Since VHDL-2008 you can use `std.env.stop;` to stop a simulation from any process or subprogram. It doesn't need any special clock disabling (which might get tricky in big designs) and it doesn't produce additional output lines like an `assert`-statement would produce.